# Dataview with two sources to display library and list content - An effective strategy for collecting & presenting assets?

Tags: list, library, content, libraries, dataview

One way of classifying the resources provided on my site is by whether they are a *file* (e.g., a PDF, Word Doc, Excel file) or a *link.* Links can be to an internal resource, i.e., another HTML page, or an external resource, i.e., content on a different website. Beside the distinction between *file* and *source*, all other categories of metadata are the same.

In SharePoint 2010 Foundation, I have a library for all the *file* resources, and a list for all the *link* resources.

I want to provide two things: 1) an easy way for content owners to add resources, and thus the single library and single list system, and 2) a "merged" view of those two resource sources from which I can generate displays of those resources filtered and grouped in myriad ways.

I figure the first goal is covered because my content owners only need to work with two nearly identical interfaces to add assets. I'm wondering about the second part...

Is it a reasonable solution to create a DataView that pulls its data from these two sources? Is this the best - or only - way to do what I'm shooting for?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

DataView will work fine, there is no "best" answer here, it depends on your abilities and exactly what you want to achieve.

You didn't state version and level of your SharePoint environment. but...

- if you are using 2007/2010/2013 Enterprise SKU you can use the
  Content Query Web Part (CQWP)
- If you have 2013 Enterprise or O365 you also have the option of using
  the Content Search web part.

If you are using any version you may also be able to leverage the Search Results web part.

My preferred approach with 2013 is to content search or search results with a custom display template.

For 2010/2007 I would look at the Content Query Web Part or data view webpart.  Both can be customized by modifying the XSLT code.

Another option is going totally custom and using SPServices and creating your own data table layout (this essentially is what you are doing with display templates on 2013).

Comment: Sorry, I added that I'm on SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Comment: You are pretty limited then, using the DVWP or custom HTML/Javascript solution.  If you add Search Server Express, you can gain access to the search result web part, but for just this I would stick with DVWP